# Can we tweak the 'is not about identification' line in Help?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

In [What topics can I ask about here?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) the newly added line in *'Don't ask about:'* regarding identification states

- Identification of band/genera/artist/ect.

Can we specifically add 'song/tune/' to that & rearrange the others into a slightly more logical progression?
[& fix the spelling of 'genre' & 'etc' while we're at it;)
To end up with

- Identification of song/tune/band/artist/genre etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just edited it to fix this. I also replaced the slashes with commas as the commas flow nicer than the slashes as the list increases.

Comment: Looks a lot better, thanks. I was going to vtc one this morning & add my rubber-stamp 'please read this', when I noticed it didn't actually specifically say 'song identification' so I wanted future posters to have a better chance - or have something to point directly to if they did fail to read it.

Comment: Actually… I just realised it still ends band, genre, artist; which I still think would be better grouped as band, artist, genre. No biggie, just would satisfy my OCD ;))